# What is the meaning of this phrase "an absolute snip for the 2.30"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have no idea or no guess about the phrase "an absolute snip for the 2.30". Could anyone help me understand this phrase?
This is from the play written by A. A. Milne about 100 years ago.

> Bertie (taking a large envelope from his pocket). The Prime Minister's compliments, and would you rather have a Baronetcy or an absolute snip for the 2.30?
> Mannock (not surprised). Ah! It's all right, then?
> Bertie. Very much all right. Between ourselves, it's a damn good speech. I read it to him. He just lay there, without a movement. Absorbed.
>
> Mannock: The Rt. Hon. R. Selby Mannock, M.P.
> Bertie: Secretary of Prime Minister

Answer (score 2):

A 'snip' is a bargain or very good thing to be involved in financially. The time (2.30) is that of a horse race. It is a tip for a bet on a horse where the odds are surprisingly good.

> snip noun (CHEAP PRODUCT)
> UK informal
> a product that is being sold cheaply, for less than you would expect:
> The sunglasses are now available in major stores, a snip at £12 a pair.

[Snip (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snip)